# Plot standard errors(std/sqrt(N)) usiiing yerr() on a bar plot graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to Python. I'm trying to plot a box plot for a [sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mg7SbwydDaYzVcVv6o0LCBuYEQ4BYwQt_rGQWIkFsCs/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to plot box plots of mean value of the shared data. I got that part of the code. I'm also trying to plot standard error values on this box plot using `yerr()`.

**My code**:

```
data3=pd.read_csv('demo1.csv')
names=['brow', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre']
d=[data3['brow'].mean(),data3['harr'].mean(),data3['hage'].mean(),data3['buch'].mean(),data3['mcre'].mean()]
N=len(data3['co'])
l=math.sqrt(N)
k=[(data3['brow'].std())/l,(data3['harr'].std())/l,(data3['hage'].std())/l,(data3['buch'].std())/l,(data3['mcre'].std())/l,(data3['phil'].std())/l,(data3['moor'].std())/l]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(names,d)
plt.bar(len(names),d,yerr=k,align='center',alpha=0.5,ecolor='black',capsize=10)
```

Im getting an image such as this [image]

But I want the black lines to be against each bar graph and not as a new bar in the plot with all of them together. How can I change this. Am I using the plt the wrong way? Please help.

Comment: Why dont you use `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot` ?

Comment: But I want to build a Bar Plot. I'm yet to learn box plot completely, I do think it's easy to do it on the box but can't I get something like this with bar plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you were trying to do with your second call to `plt.bar()`

```
import math
names=['brow', 'harr', 'hage', 'buch', 'mcre']

data3 = pd.DataFrame({n: np.random.normal(loc=np.random.randint(5,10), scale=np.random.randint(1,10), size=(100,)) for n in names})


d=data3[names].mean()
N=100
l=math.sqrt(N)
k=data3[names].std()/l
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(names,d,yerr=k,align='center',alpha=0.5,ecolor='black',capsize=10)
```

[image]